# Instragram send like to image show error for app

Tags: ios, xcode, instagram

I have created app on Instagram and got access token and client Id.
My issue is that when I send like to image using API method that is showing me error:

```
    meta =     {
        code = 400;
        "error_message" = "you cannot like this media";
        "error_type" = APINotAllowedError;
    };
}
```

So like is not being sent to Image. I can explicitly able to like that image from the Instagram app. So may be the issue is not related to image's privacy. Can anyone help me for this issue?

****************** Edit ******************

After I check I am able to send Like from the API consolr of the Instagram for same `media_id` with response 200/OK, but from my app issue is still there.

Can I solve this by changing the APP ID AND APP SECRET ?
Please reply

Answer (score 0):

1 - Double check if you are using correct access token

2 - How much likes did you in a hour? Pay attention to it and respect the limits. Take a look here: http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Comment: we are sending signed API calls now. and not reached to the limit. 
for few users that is working but for so many users account that is showing above error.. Even for single like in a day. I am trying since so many days.